# How do you know what expression OCaml expects? (pattern matching)

Tags: design-patterns, ocaml, matching

I'm doing pattern matching and I keep getting an error saying the expression was expected type 'a list. Why is that?

Comment: I think you'll have to give example code or an interpreter session to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

If ocaml expects an expression to have a certain type that's because you're performing some operation on that expression, which only works with that type. So in this case you're probably pattern matching on the expression using list patterns (i.e. the constructors `::` and `nil` or list literals like `[x,y,z]`).

If you try that with an expression that does not evaluate to a list, that's of course an error, which is what the error message is telling you.